# Send Return Code back from child script to the Parent script

Tags: return-value

My child script can create a rc=110 when a FTPed file is not located.  The Parent script sets the Error Handling RC=1.  I want the Error Handling to set to the RC created in child script.  Any ideas?

Comment: And your script is written in?!?

Answer (score 0):

What operating system?  In linux you can forward the paramenter using standard input/output using the |  (pipe)

```
./script | ./binaryName
```

This forwards the output of ./script as the input of ./binaryName
and in your main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
//Don't use argv[0]!
char* yourOutput = argv[1];
return 0;
}
```

I just realized your "parent" is a script too.  Which language is this?  All the languages I've worked with have a manner to get arguements like I just showed you in C++.